# making a new list with comparing a list with the Field of a Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a list of string

```
 List<string> totalTags =new ({"Test1","test2","Test3","test4","Test5"});
```

I want to search the table Tags and find list of following Name and make a list for their associated Ids
The Tag Table has two fields ,Id and Name.
like

```
  Id     Name
 ==============
   1      Test1
   2      Test4
```

and so on

```
  var IdList= _context.Tags.Where(t2 => !totalTags .Any(t1 => t2.Name.Contains(t1))).Select(p=>p.Id).ToList();
```

and want to have

```
  IdList ={"1","2",....}     (the Id of the rest)
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from `Tags` and expect result?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Contains` method like

```
var idsList = _context.Tags
                      .Where(t=> totalTags.Contains(t.Name))
                      .Select(t=> t.Id)
                      .ToList()
```

Comment: If he wants the the tags which are in the TotalTags list, then ! should be removed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all `ids` from `_context.Tags` where `tag.Name` should present in `totalTags` list, then try below

```
 var IdList = _context.Tags
     .Where(x => totalTags.Contains(x.Name)) //No `!` operator
     .Select(x => x.Id)
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to compare `t1 == t2.Name` in `Any` becasue `t2.Name` is a string instead of list, otherwise that will compare by `char`.

```
var IdList = _context.Tags.Where(t2 => totalTags.Any(t1 => t1 == t2.Name)).Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```